# How to set domain if differ from SIP server?

Tags: domain, sip, xlite

I have server name differs from SIP account's domain name (in SIP the domain name is just a user group and may not coincide with DNS name).

I see no "domain" field in Jitsi account configuration. Setting "name@domain" does not work. Also I see no separate domain name fields in X-Lite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "name@sipdomain" in the configuration worked for me. You can set the DNS name of the registrar in a different configuration tab.

Comment: I have no DNS name for sip server it is accessible only by IP. Simultaneously I have logical (fake, not in DNS) domain name for my sip account.

Comment: Have you tried entering the IP address in the registrar address box?

Comment: I guess these were server-side problems